# Jekyll seems to have stopped processing pages

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll

I've been using Jekyll (with the auto option set to true, so it auto builds to the _site folder) on a site for a few weeks, and everything has been working fine.

The posts were in a structure like this

```
/language/_posts/yyyy-mm-dd-filename.html
```

and so jekyll built them out into the _site folder and the results looked like this:

```
/language/filename.html
```

Recently the folder structure of the site had to change, to duplicate the existing content out into 4 regions, which has quadrupled the number of posts on the site.

So I updated the structure and the posts are now in a subfolders like this:

```
/region/language/_posts/yyyy-mm-dd-filename.html
```

so jekyll builds them out into the _site folder which should result in:

```
/region/language/filename.html
```

this worked at first, but as I've added more regions, jekyll seems to stop processing the files, and I can't seem to figure out why.

Becuase I've inherited this site off someone else, it is using the yyyy-mm-dd in the filename structure in a bit of a hacky way, to get the pages to appear in the 'order' they are meant to. I'm wondering if this might have anything to do with it.

The dates on my posts range from `0000-01-01` to `0039-10-10` - so they're not really being used as actual dates, but I wouldn't have thought this would affect jekyll processing them.

So my thoughts are:

1) Does jekyll have any sort of maximum page/post limits? I have  11 posts x 9 languages x 4 regions = 396 posts

2) Would the fact that there are over 30 'years' between posts cause any problems?

Any help much appreciated, I'm more of a front end kinda guy...

Cheers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is likely an error message (syntax or otherwise) being masked by jekyll. When jekyll is in `auto` mode, it sometimes doesn't show them. Try removing the generated folder (by default on `_site/` and running jekyll with the `--no-auto` parameter:

```
rm -rf _site
jekyll --no-auto
```

If there are errors, this should show them.

Comment: I did that, there were no errors shown, but that did manage to build to site out correctly. Thanks!

Comment: No worries. Jekyll doesn't erase the _site folder every time it's regenerated. You were seeing old versions of the pages, that's all. I'm glad I could help!